# Data is not Updating in firebase(Android)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Data is not Updating in the FireBase It keeps Loading for long time but not Updating(Android App)
In One Screen I Kept One Image Button which it Selects From Gallery An Remaining two are Edit Text Buttons One is Title Field and another One is Description Field then after clicking Post Button it should post the image along with title,Description field but after clicking on Post it Continuously Loading with out posting

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

public class PostActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageButton mSelectImage;
    private EditText mPostTitle;
    private EditText mPostDesc;
    private Button mSubmitBtn;
    private Uri mImageUri = null;
    private StorageReference mStorage;
    private ProgressDialog mProgress;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseUser mCurrentUser;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseUser;

    private static final int GALLERY_REQUEST = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_post);

        mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Blog");

        mSelectImage = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageSelect);

        mPostTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.titleField);
        mPostDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.descField);
        mSubmitBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitBtn);
        mProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mCurrentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        mDatabaseUser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(mCurrentUser.getUid());

        mSelectImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY_REQUEST);
            }
        });

        mSubmitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startPosting();
            }
        });
    }

    private void startPosting() {

        //Get values from title and description
        mProgress.setMessage("Uploading to DB...");

        final String title_val = mPostTitle.getText().toString().trim();
        final String desc_val = mPostDesc.getText().toString().trim();

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(title_val) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(desc_val) && mImageUri != null) {
            //start uploading to DB
            //authenticate before letting upload(not in this app)
            mProgress.show();

            StorageReference filePath = mStorage.child("Blog_Images").child(mImageUri.getLastPathSegment());

            filePath.putFile(mImageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests")
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                    final Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

                    final DatabaseReference newPost = mDatabase.push();//push creates unique random ID(no overwriting)

                    if(mDatabaseUser != null) {
                        mDatabaseUser.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                newPost.child("title").setValue(title_val);
                                newPost.child("desc").setValue(desc_val);
                                newPost.child("image").setValue(downloadUrl.toString());
                                newPost.child("uid").setValue(mCurrentUser.getUid());
                                newPost.child("username").setValue(dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                            startActivity(new Intent(PostActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                                        }
                                    }
                                });

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });
                    }

                    mProgress.dismiss();

                    startActivity(new Intent(PostActivity.this, MainActivity.class));

                }
            });

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            mImageUri = data.getData();
            mSelectImage.setImageURI(mImageUri);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, please add more detail to your question so people can better help you find your answer. Also, read about [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for future questions.

Comment: Now Once check it @GrayCygnus

Answer (score 0):

First remove `if(mDatabaseUser != null) {..}` and then instead of `mDatabaseUser.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {..}`, do it like this: `mDatabaseUser.child(mCurrentUser.getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {...}` after you have removed `.child(mCurrentUser.getUid())` from `mDatabaseUser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(mCurrentUser.getUid());` at the top of your code.

And also the second `startActivity(new Intent(PostActivity.this, MainActivity.class));` is not required.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't thoroughly looked at all the code you posted and may not understand your processing completely. There are two things that might be causing some of the problems you described.

In FirebaseHelper, method onChildChanged() calls fetchData(), which adds the changed section details to the array list. Shouldn't you be updating the existing section details instead of adding them again? Also, in onChildRemoved(), the section details are not removed from the array list. Don't they need to be removed?

In CustomAdapter the click listeners for your buttons add anonymous ValueEventListeners. Because they are anonymous, you have no way of removing them when they are no longer needed. ValueEventListeners added with addValueEventListener() remain active until removed. If your goal is to get the data once, use addListenerForSingleValueEvent().

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    note.setTitle(titleTextView.getText().toString());
    note.setDescription(descriptionTextView.getText().toString());
    database.child("notes").child(note.getUid()).setValue(note);
    finish();
}
});
```